# Route issue with two interface network

Tags: linux, networking, routing, dhcp

So I'm not entirely sure if this is possible, I've just been trying a few things in the hope of getting a working solution.

I've set up my device's eth0 successfully through dnsmasq, serving as a DHCP server. This works quite well. As I suspect I will need more than 254 clients, I've opted to create a /20 network.

Now, I've also set up my device's wlan0 successfully to tie into the same dnsmasq, giving out IP's connecting to it's AP. This, I was also able to do.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:92:22:c6
          inet addr:1.0.0.1  Bcast:1.0.15.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe92:22c6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2113 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:323 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:134909 (131.7 KiB)  TX bytes:21087 (20.5 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3576 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3576 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:252704 (246.7 KiB)  TX bytes:252704 (246.7 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:c7:77:93
          inet addr:1.0.0.2  Bcast:1.0.15.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fec7:7793/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:938 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3552 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:150695 (147.1 KiB)  TX bytes:279694 (273.1 KiB)
```

and my dnsmasq being:

```
interface=eth0,wlan0
listen-address=1.0.0.1,1.0.0.2
bind-interfaces
local=/argos/
domain=argos
domain-needed
bogus-priv
dhcp-sequential-ip
dhcp-range=1.0.0.3,1.0.15.254,255.255.240.0,36h
```

This seemed to have all worked out great, except, I'm not able to ping clients and clients are not able to ping the device.

However, if I specify which interface to use for the pinging, it does seem to find it's way:

```
ping -I eth0 1.0.0.3
```

So I'm thinking there's a whole mixup at the routing. How can I solve this? Considering that whether or not you're connected over eth0 or wlan0, the device is the same I'm at a loss why this doesn't work.

Comment: Please use proper IP ranges. 1.0.0.* are public IPs and can appear outside your network, 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 is in the [private address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces) and free for use.

Answer (score 1):

One subnet should belong to *one* interface, as it basically describes which hosts are in the same *broadcast domain* (i.e. can reach each other directly at Ethernet layer-2).

- If hosts within the same subnet try to reach each other, they won't try to use the router – instead they'll try to directly learn each other's MAC address (using ARP).
- If traffic comes from another network (or from the router itself), your router is not going to try and divine out whether packets for each individual host should be routed through eth0 or wlan0 – it'll use the same /20 route (usually through eth0) for all of them.

If you want a single subnet, the right way to "link" both interfaces would be to set up a *bridge* interface (which acts like a switch, forwarding Ethernet frames based on MAC address) and set both physical interfaces as bridge ports.

(The IP address and dnsmasq would also be set up on the br0 interface instead of eth0.)

Otherwise, use different subnets for wired and wireless.